# Dataprep.eda inside Google Colab

Tags: jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

Does anybody tried using `dataprep.eda` inside Google Colab? It works fine when using my local jupyiter notebook, but when trying to use this package in colab the figure doesn't show up. I'm a bit lost.

Comment: Have you thought about perhaps including some code so we might be able to help? That and perhaps what steps you've taken would be really helpful in helping you.

Answer (score 0):

there is an issue open in github

https://github.com/sfu-db/dataprep/issues/102#issuecomment-654321665

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue. Just run this code, then any plot will be displayed correctly in Colab

```py
def _report_repr_html_(self):
    from bokeh.io.notebook import load_notebook
    from bokeh.embed.notebook import notebook_content

    load_notebook(hide_banner=True)
    (script, div, cell_doc) = notebook_content(self.to_render)
    return f'{div}<script>{script}</script>'

from dataprep.eda.report import Report
Report._repr_html_ = _report_repr_html_
```

Answer (score 0):

It now works with only two steps:

```
!pip install dataprep

# Restart the runtime
```

Comment: The package installs but when i run create_report(df).show_browser(), the results tab does not open